# how to set mtu on specfic udp connection?

Tags: iptables, nftables, fragmentation

is there iptables target to fragment packets, let say i have packet with length 1280 i want to split this packet into smaller 5 packets with maximum length equal 250 ,
is it possible to use firewall in linux (nftables, iptables) to fragment packet or is there a way in general ?

can i use virtual interface with maximum mtu of 250 and let it deal with udp connection ?
if it possible how to do that

Comment: UDP is connectionless, so you do not have UDP connections. Also, packet fragmentation is pretty much deprecated. Many businesses now drop packet fragments to prevent fragmentation attacks, and IPv6 has eliminated fragmentation in the path, requiring a minimum MTU of 1280 in a path. The correct way is to use PMTUD to discover the minimum MTU in the path, or to break your UDP messages into smaller chunks prior to sending them.